# Zebra-strip for tables using ng-repeat

Tags: html, angularjs

I am display large set of data content in table using ng-repeat and it contains only one `<tr>` element. I am trying to display odd row in one color and even row in another color. I am not getting how to display the striped color for single row by making use of ng-repeat. Please let me know where I am going wrong.

HTML:

```
<thead class="rowhead"> 
  <tr>
    <th class="mid">Sl.</th>
    <th id="tnm">Name</th>
    <th class="mid">Age</th>
    <th class="mid">Members</th>
    <th class="mid">View-content</th>
    <th class="mid">on-going-Process</th>
  </tr>
</thead>

 <tbody ng-repeat="info in cspinfo">
   <tr class="clr">
     <td>{{$index+1}}</td>
     <td id="bnm">{{info.name}}</td>
     <td>{{info.age}}</td>
     <td>{{info.member}}</td>
     <td>{{info.View-content}}</td>
     <td>{{on-going-Process}}</td>           
   </tr>
 </tbody>
```

Answer (score 4):

You  can directly select the odd and even rows of table using the selector in css and apply style you need. You don't have to worry about the applying class to each row you create using ng-repeat.

tr:nth-child(odd){
  background-color: #yourcolor
}
tr:nth-child(even){
  background-color: #yourcolor
}

Here you can read more about css selectors https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Anth-child

Comment: the logic what you have said is right. But here small issue will going to occur. If i use the nth child, <thead> is also changing it's color

Comment: you can only select children of tbody tag rather than table  tag or you can add separate class for thead for managing colour

Comment: To only affect the children in the tbody of this particular table, use `thead.rowhead + tbody tr:nth-child(odd)` and `thead.rowhead + tbody tr:nth-child(even)` for selectors.

Answer (score 1):

In your css define a rule for the style. Then in your html:

```
<tbody>
    <tr class="clr" ng-class="{style-created: $index % 2 === 0}" ng-repeat="info in cspinfo">
       <td>{{$index+1}}</td>
       <td id="bnm">{{info.name}}</td>
       <td>{{info.age}}</td>
       <td>{{info.member}}</td>
       <td>{{info.View-content}}</td>
       <td>{{on-going-Process}}</td>           
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: the logic what you have said is right. But here small issue will going to occur. If i use the  nth child, <thead> is also changing it's color